# How to display latest 5 posts by pub date?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

So I have this model :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='w')
    description = models.TextField(default='', max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def edit_text(self, text):
        self.text = text

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'creation_date'
```

My view:

```
def blog(request):
return render_to_response('home/blog.html', {
    'posts': Post.objects.filter()[:5]
})
```

and template :

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <a class = "titles">{{ post.title }}</a>
        <p class = "Parg">{{ post.description }}</a>
        <br>
        <br>
 {% endfor %}
```

And I want in my template to be shown latest 5 posts(by date) and if I press "See more" display next 5 posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the latest 5 posts (ordered by `creation_date`) to the template using `order_by`:

```
def blog(request):
    return render_to_response('home/blog.html', {
        'posts': Post.objects.order_by('-creation_date')[:5]
    })
```

The `-` preceding `creation_date` indicates that the dates returned will be in descending order, ie the most recent date first.

To add the functionality to display the next 5 posts, I would return the 10 most recent `Post`s to the template using the method I have suggested, and then manipulate these using another method (perhaps basic JavaScript),

Answer (score 0):

```
def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'home/blog.html', {
        'posts': Post.objects.order_by('-creation_date')[:5]
    })
```

`render` instead of `render_to_response`, which takes care of context instance for you.